# Adding Image PHPWord in Laravel

Tags: laravel, phpword

So I want to add an header image to my document in PHPWord in Laravel.
So this is my code

```
public function generateDocx()
{
    $phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
    $section = $phpWord->addSection();

    $headerLogo = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/img/logoAnevBulanan.png';
    $section->addImage($headerLogo);

    // Bunch of line to download the docx
}
```

And I got Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded, when I try the other method from the [documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/samples/Sample_13_Images.php), I still got the same error. I try to use `asset()`  helper from laravel and still did not work

Answer (score 2):

Try getting your image using local path instead of URL

```
$source = file_get_contents('/path/to/my/images/earth.jpg');
$textrun->addImage($source);
```

Refer to documentation : https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/elements.html#images